# Custom Flutter Notification Plugin

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm currently developing a notification plugin to be used with my music application that I'm converting over to Flutter. Thus far it's all been working perfectly, however though I ran into a problem which I'm not sure how to handle.

My plugin requires an image which is displayed in the notification, The images are all hosted and fetched via url (https://example.com/img.png) so that eliminates the loading via file system

Now the problem is that, I would like to keep the plugin as lightweight as possible (would rather not add Glide etc).

Is there anyway I can pass the bitmap directly from flutter to the plugin ? perhaps the same way that we can pass strings ?

```
static Future example(String data) async {
  await _channel.invokeMethod('example', {
    'data' : data
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance guys, Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did that answer help? If so, it's conventional to 'accept' the answer - which gives us both a bump in reputation :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StandardMessageCodec which converts between Dart and native types handles

```
acyclic values of these forms:
null
[bool]s
[num]s
[String]s
[Uint8List]s, [Int32List]s, [Int64List]s, [Float64List]s
[List]s of supported values
[Map]s from supported values to supported values
```

so you can pass a Uint8List (in place of String data) in your example, and you will get a `byte[]` or `FlutterStandardTypedData` on the native side for Android and iOS respectively.

It's not clear whether you need the png on the native side or the decoded bitmap.

To fetch the png you could use the http package

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:http/http.dart';

  Uint8List png =
      (await get('http://www.barcodes4.me/barcode/c39/123456.png')).bodyBytes;
```

and pass Uint8List png to invokeMethod. If you need to convert to a bitmap first (though you should avoid this if you can, as the bitmap will be much larger than the png), use the image package.

```
import 'package:image/image.dart';

  Image image = decodeImage(png); // if known to be a PNG, could call decodePng
  Map<String, dynamic> imageData = {
    'width': image.width,
    'height': image.height,
    'bitmap': image.getBytes(),
  };
```

and pass Map imageData to invokeMethod. This will appear at the native end as a `java.util.HashMap` or `NSDictionary`.

Comment: I agree with this solution, fetching data separately and then sending callback from native to dart using plugin